# How do I use hash map with arrayList as value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am using a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList>`. In my `ArrayList`,
the second element is an `int` that I need to increment that by one. How can I achieve this?

```
public class IncrementAge {

    /** integer is key; value is ArrayList. */
    Map<Integer, ArrayList> idNumber = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList>();

    /** array that contains name and age (only two elements). */
    ArrayList<> person = new ArrayList();

    /** name is 1st(0) element in array while age is second(1) element. */
    this.person.add(0, "jose");
    this.person.add(1, 32);

    /** place this object in hashMap with key=0; obj=person. */

    idNumber.put(0, this.person);
}
```

How should I increment age of this `idNumber` object,
based on a key value of `HashSet`?

Comment: You need to give the object name to the ArrayList template.

Comment: This is a horrible design. Please make a Person class, and let the Map be of type <Integer, Person>. Then you can look up a person in the Map and use the methods of Person to change attributes.

Comment: I know…design stinks, but how would I go about accessing Arraylist element when it is in a hash map.

Comment: You need to retrieve the ArrayList from the Map first, then to get the element by index.

Comment: @user2943394 You access Arraylist elements the same way, no matter if the List is actually in a Map or elsewhere.

Comment: When you solve this, you'll see that it takes a whole bunch of code, and non-typesafe code at that---which is why your design stinks.

Comment: This is probably a homework. If so, resolve it by yourself, and after that write a second solution with a better design as suggested, then amuse your professor with two solutions instead of one.

Comment: not hw. trying to get to know java's built-in data structures. just playing around with it

Comment: They are not "built in". They are ordinary classes that happen to live in the standard library that is provided when you download Java. Classes the compiler knows about are probably just Object and the wrappers for primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet of code will help you to increment age.

```
Integer age = (Integer)idNumber.get(0).remove(1);
age++;
idNumber.get(0).add(1, age);
```

Explanation:
- idNumber.get(0): Here 0 represents the key for the person whose age needs to be incremented
- remove(1): will remove and return the object at index 1 from ArrayList person i.e. age.
- age++: will increment the age by 1
- add(1, age): Adds the age object to the ArrayList at index 1.

But as already suggested this way of writing code is not good practice and instead of using ArrayList preson, better approach is to design Person class and store its object in HashMap as value.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you. ...even on-the-fly pseudocode gets criticized around here…lol

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to spit on a person asking for your help.

@user2943394, yes, your design is not good here. OO exists for such reasons to ease up your coding.

Here's a quick example how you can do what you need to do so it looks pretty nice. Take note, though, that this is just a 2 minute code scrap, not the state of the art design.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    // Constructor
    public Person(...) {
        ...
    }


    // Getters & Setters
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        // you dont want to pass the wrong value, so you might want to check for that also
        this.age = age;
    }

    ...
}

public class PersonRepo {
    private Map<Integer, Person> personMap;

    public PersonRepo() {
        this.personMap = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();

        loadPersons();
    }

    private void loadPersons() {
        // load them from text file, or whicever source you have
        // or simply add them manually
    }

    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return this.personMap.get(id);
    }
}

public class PersonService {
    private PersonRepo personRepo;

    public PersonService() {
        this.personRepo = new PersonRepo();
    }

    public void incrementPersonAge(int personId, int step) {
        Person person = this.personRepo.getPersonById(personId);
        int oldAge = person.getAge();
        int newAge = oldAge + step;
        person.setAge(newAge);
    }
}

public class PersonTester() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonService personService = new PersonService();

        personService.incrementPersonAge(12, 1);
    }
}
```

If you're really adamant with going your way, you can do something like this:

```
int oldAge = (Integer) idNmber.get(0).get(1);
int newAge = oldAge + 1;
idNumber.get(0).set(1, newAge);
```